# How to commit files in detached head mode to a branch

Tags: git, git-commit, git-detached-head

I ended up in a weird situation where I checkout a previous commit on my branch v4.1.0-rc12. I've modified some files around and I want to commit it to the v4.1.0-rc12 branch.

Now that HEAD pointer is in detached mode since I checked out a previous commit, how do I commit this changes to v4.1.0-rc12 branch in detached mode?

I wish I had done "revert" instead of "checkout" the commit hash.

Is there any possible solution to commit the edited files and add it to my v4.1.0-rc12 branch?

This is what my "git reflog" shows

```
 441bfac HEAD@{0}: commit: Resolved #110
 dc00e4f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from v4.1.0-rc12 to dc00e4f
 2542748 HEAD@{2}: commit: Login & SignUp revamp (Broken)
 dc00e4f HEAD@{3}: commit: Resolved #109 and #110
 4472914 HEAD@{4}: commit: Resolved #108
```

I want to save 441bfac to v4.1.0-rc12

Any help or notion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

```
$ git checkout v4.1.0-rc12 branch
(see if it succeeds, if so):
$ git add ...     # if / as needed
$ git commit
```

This *might not* work, because the `git checkout` step will refuse to switch to the branch, if (and only if) said switching will wipe out the changes you've already made.

The `git checkout` step will *succeed*, and carry your changes along, if it can.

If the `git checkout` step succeeds, this is by far the easiest way to deal with it all.  If not, proceed to alternate methods.

---

Method 2 ([avi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150883/1256452)):

```
$ git checkout -b tempbranch
$ git add ...      # as and if needed
$ git commit
```

This (the `-b tempbranch`) creates a new, temporary branch pointing to the commit at which you detached your HEAD earlier.  The `git commit` then creates a new commit on this temporary branch:

```
          o--o--o   <-- v4.1.0-rc12 branch
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o         <-- tempbranch
```

Now you can `git checkout` whatever you like, and the commit you made on `tempbranch` is permanently stored in your repository (well, permanent unless/until you delete the name `tempbranch`), which enables you to copy stuff from it whenever you want.

---

Method 3:

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout v4.1.0-rc12 branch
$ git stash apply    # or even "git stash pop" but I prefer "apply"
... check everything out ...
... if it all looks right ...
$ git stash drop     # "git stash pop" means "apply and then auto-drop"
```

What `git stash` does is make a commit (well, actually *two* commits) that are not on *any* branch.  The effect is the same as when you make the temporary branch.  That leaves the problem of deleting the non-branch when you're done with it, so `git stash drop` deletes the unnamed non-branch that holds the commits.

The `git stash apply` step essentially (though it's more complicated than this) cherry-picks the commit that `git stash` made, wherever you are now: so this is like cherry-picking the commit you made on `tempbranch`.

Note that `git stash pop` automatically invokes `git stash drop`, even if the result of the `git stash apply` is a mess, you've lost your temporary commits if you `pop` but not if you `apply`.  If everything goes *well* there's no real difference and `pop` is more convenient; this is just a case of leaving a better [bread-crumb trail](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrailOfBreadCrumbs) in case things go bad.

---

(My personal preference, incidentally, is for method 1 first if possible, then usually 2, then 3, but sometimes—when I am sure it's going to work—I'll prefer method 3 to method 2.)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

First, create new branch from your previous commit, checkout to newly created branch, update your files and than commit  the changes.
After that you can merge your changes to any branch.

Comment: If I create and checkout a new branch won't I loose my current work in the detached mode?

Comment: @SamuelRobert: No, git guarantees that a checkout is non-destructive. It will keep uncommited modifications, or refuse the checkout if it cannot due to conflicts. See [git checkout < branch > failure for local changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450983/git-checkout-branch-failure-for-local-changes) for an explanation.

Comment: Yes , you will loose your current modification from detached branch. First commit your changes on detached head and than make new branch from detached head.

Comment: Ya that's is great

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, and I solved in a way that, in your case, would be:

```
git checkout v4.1.0-rc12
git merge 441bfac
```

General case:

```
git checkout branch-to-have-the-changes
git merge changes-that-we-previously-made-id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your new changes are committed to a detached HEAD, and you want v4.1.0-rc12 to point to that same commit also:

```
git branch -f v4.1.0-rc12 HEAD
git checkout v4.1.0-rc12
```